# Enviar dados de uma tabela html para php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Olá

Tenho uma tabela

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Codigo</th>
    <th>Nome</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>`insira o código aqui`
     <td>1</td>
     <td>Carlos</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>Charles</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>José</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Gostaria de saber se tem como "pegar" esses dados e enviar para php
pode ser via json ou javascript mesmo

Tentei usar isso:

```
var dadosDataTabela = [];

function verificarTabela() {
    $('.item').each(function () {
       var todos_itens = {
           codigo   : $(this).children()[0].innerText,
           nome     : $(this).children()[1].innerHTML,

       };
       dadosDataTabela.push(todos_itens);
    });
}
```

e para enviar `JSON.stringify(dadosDataTabela),`

Mas ainda não tive sucesso como se recebe no php. Para depois enviar esses dados para o banco

Comment: Se esta usando jQuery, existe uma biblioteca para isso: http://jsfiddle.net/cCzqn/80/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe uma biblioteca jQuery que faz o trabalho duro ([table-to-json](http://www.developerdan.com/table-to-json/)), e pelo que pude ver da documentação, ele é bem customizável:

```js
$('#converter-tabela').click( function() {
  var table = $('#tabela').tableToJSON();
  console.log(table);
  alert(JSON.stringify(table));  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/table-to-json@1.0.0/lib/jquery.tabletojson.min.js" integrity="sha256-H8xrCe0tZFi/C2CgxkmiGksqVaxhW0PFcUKZJZo1yNU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table id="tabela">
  <thead>
    <th>Codigo</th>
    <th>Nome</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>Carlos</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>Charles</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>José</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="converter-tabela" >Converter</button>
```

Comment: legal! Desculpe a minha inexperiência, e para receber no php seria o json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['tabela'])  ? Se for como faço pra exibir no php?

Comment: Depende de como deseja receber esses dados no php, veja que ele cria um array com cada linha sendo um objeto, para testar eu recomendo fazer um `var_dump($_POST/$_GET/$_REQUEST)`

Comment: eu quero salvar esses dados no banco

Answer (score 1):

Com php pode fazer assim: coloque o código html da tabela na variável $tab

```
$tab = "
<table>
<thead>
<th>Codigo</th>
<th>Nome</th>
</thead>
<tr>`insira o código aqui`
<td>1</td>
<td>Carlos</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>Charles</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>José</td>
</tr>
</table>
";

$er = "/<td(.*?)?>(.*?)+<\/td>/i";
preg_match_all ($er, $tab, $matches);

$td00=$matches[0][0];
$td01=$matches[0][1];
$td02=$matches[0][2];
$td03=$matches[0][3];
$td04=$matches[0][4];
$td05=$matches[0][5];

...("Insert into tabela (coluna1,coluna2,coluna3,coluna4,coluna5,coluna6)
values ('".$td00."','".$td01."','".$td02."','".$td03."','".$td04."','".$td05."')");
```

A função preg_match_all() retornará um número inteiro com a quantidade de ocorrências encontradas pela expressão regular.

A função aceita 5 parâmetros, sendo 3 obrigatórios e 2 opcionais.   [saiba mais em preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
$resultado = preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
```

- $pattern será a expressão regultar,
- $subject será o texto (assunto) que a expressão irá pesquisar
- $matches será um array com as ocorrências (trechos encontrados).

> Ou também pode pegar os dados da variável $tab de um arquivo

```
$file = fopen("filename.html","r");

while(! feof($file))
  {
  $result=$result. fgets($file);
  }
fclose($file);

$tab = ".$result.";
```

Comment: Ou utiliza diretamente a classe [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php).

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando a lib que o @Bonifazio indicou:

dados.php

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode($_POST['dados_tabela'], true);

    /*
       $data terá o seguinte valor:
       array(
          array(
              "Codigo": 1
              , "Nome": "Carlos"
          )
          ... os demais nomes
       )

       É só percorrer o array com um laço e gravar no banco
    */
    // Retorna a confirmação para o javascript
    echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
?>
```

index.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.developerdan.com/table-to-json/javascripts/jquery.tabletojson.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#converter-tabela').click( function() {
        var table = $('#tabela').tableToJSON();
        console.log(table);
        alert(JSON.stringify(table)); 
        // Você envia os dados para o PHP utilizando AJAX
        $.ajax({
            // Enviamos os dados da tabela para um script PHP
            url: 'dados.php'
            , data: { dados_tabela: table }
            , method: 'POST'
        }).then(function(result) {
           // No retorno, apenas confirmamos
           if (result.success) {
               alert('Enviado para o servidor com sucesso!');
           }
       });
     });
</script>

<table id="tabela">
  <thead>
    <th>Codigo</th>
    <th>Nome</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>Carlos</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>Charles</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>José</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="converter-tabela" >Converter</button>
```